# Stop the refresh of SQL Query

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I set up a SQL Connection and a query that loads data into my sheet.
I used the macro recording option to set up a macro that refreshes my query. This works well.

However, I also want a macro to stop the refresh, so that the user can cancel the query if it runs too long.

Has anyone an idea how I can proceed with that?
My sql query is called "Data" if that helps

Comment: [Without code, it is very hard to help you](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/).

Comment: You can set a data connection to not update automatically, but once it runs, you cannot stop it from VBA (=macro). This is because the macro will wait until the SQL query is complete, before the next action can be executed.

Comment: *so that the user can cancel the query if it runs too long* Not possible and the reason is what @FranzReischl said in the previous comment